# Why doesn't if(cell == nil) work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was trying to use a couple different reuse identifiers to give the user the ability to enter data without a segue...(just thought it would be nice).

This is what I tried first:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(addC && indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        UITextField *txtField = [[UITexField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 260, 30);
        [cell addsubview:txtField];
        cell.txtField.delegate = self;
        cell.txtField.text = nil;
        return cell;
```

However, I noticed that if I used the field more than once the textfield would duplicate, leaving old values underneath.
So after some reasearch I added:

```
if(cell == nil){

}
```

around the txtField initialization but it would not fire. I ended up working around this issue entirely by making a separate UITableViewCell Class but now I am trying to add
[SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)
and changing my cell from UITableViewCell to a CustomTableViewCell.

This custom utilities addon to my table and the initialization requires you use

```
if (cell == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *leftUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

        [leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07 green:0.75f blue:0.16f alpha:1.0] 
                        icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:0.35f alpha:1.0] 
                        icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0] 
                        icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"]];
        [leftUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.55f green:0.27f blue:0.07f alpha:1.0] 
                        icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"]];

        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                        title:@"More"];
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
                        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f] 
                            title:@"Delete"];

        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                        reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
                        containingTableView:_tableView // For row height and selection
                        leftUtilityButtons:leftUtilityButtons 
                        rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
        cell.delegate = self;
}
```

if have not yet implemented this addon but before when I was researching my problem and now i havent found anything.

I have also tried

```
if (cell.contentView == nil)

if (cell.contentView.subViews == nil)

if (cell.subViews == nil)
```

but for some reason it will not fire the first time like its supposed to. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question (why `cell == nil` never gets called):

The documentation for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` states that:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

What this is saying is that if you used `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in order to register the reuse identifier, which it appears you did otherwise your cells would be nil since you never instantiate one manually, you will never get a chance to instantiate one yourself.

There are a few ways to solve this issue but the best and most efficient is to just create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and add whatever custom subviews you want in your subclass if you are using one and just set the properties of the subviews each time they are reused.

So basically just move all that custom subview adding and initialization code into `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Then your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method would be rewritten as something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(addC && indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.txtField.delegate = self;
        cell.txtField.text = nil;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i could up vote you i would thats exactly how i solved my first issue but then the next one if you take a look at the SWTableViewCell he used the if(cell == nil) to replicate that. since it wont be called id have to remake his entire project pretty much to use it? theres no workaround for the time being

Comment: Nope it will still work fine by just putting the code into `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` I will edit my answer with an example of how that could work.

Comment: After trying to mock this up it looks like the default `SWTableViewCell` initializer expects a reference to the `UITableView` which is not easily accessed from that spot. Because of this I would instead recommend getting rid of your registered cells and instead structure your code to allow manual initialization of the cell like in the code examples in their docs.

Comment: ... like using static cells... I don't know if that would work the data source is sqlite through core data i'm sure there's a workaround to make a static cell work like a reusable but they have an updated version for storyboard it used quite a few different custom views... just figuring out what I want and don't want and remaking it in my own project

Answer (score 0):

If `cell` is `nil` then you got no cell back from the table view. So your `txtField` addition will have no effect regardless.

What it sounds like you want to look for is getting a cell back that already has a text field? So `cell` will **explicitly not** be `nil`.

Most programs use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` so that the lifecycle of subviews naturally matches the cell itself. In your case:

1. you should be adding to `cell.contentView`, not `cell` directly;
2. you can then probably tell whether you've added anything yet by checking `[cell.contentView.subviews count]` as the point of content view is that it is distinct from any of the other subviews that table view cells may add or remove from themselves as an ordinary part of operation.

Comment: you code still fires every time the reuse is loaded however i see why now though. although it did prevent the doubleing up so thank you