# Custom TableView Cell Reuse Code Review Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that this question has been answered before, but I am a little confused re a code review that I received. I build a custom cell call `OpeningsTableViewCell` with a custom xib for the cell. In my 
`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method my code is as follows:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"OpeningsTableViewCell";
OpeningsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (OpeningsTableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:reuseIdentifier owner:nil
                                                             options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I received a code review from a colleague that says "This will cause cell creation every time" but I have always done custom cells this way, and I cannot find any information online that differs. Wracking my brain trying to see whats wrong, any thoughts?

Comment: have you registered nib file? best way to check if cell being created each time is to put a breakpoint in the if statement

Comment: This looks OK although I long ago moved to Storyboards so may not remember the fine details. The only thing I would be concerned about would be `owner:nil`; I would expect `owner:self`. But otherwise this seems like it will not cause cell creation every time although it is old-style code. You will initially create enough cells to populate the view (plus a couple) and thereafter they will be recycled. But look into `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or storyboards so you can remove the `if (cell == nil) {...}` code section.

Comment: This looks fine, this is old style coding. Although proper code review comments should have been to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One case would be if your NIB file specifies a different cell reuse identifier.  Then all cells will have that reuseID and the `dequeue` will consequently never return a cell.  Hence you will perpetually load the NIB.  But I can't see any other problem.

You could register the NIB file for use with that reuseIdentifier (using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`), then you won't need the if (cell == nil) stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing this in interface builder but I changed to this way and got rid of the `(cell==nil)` area, lets see!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` states that:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

What this is saying is that if you used `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in order to register the reuse identifier, you will never get a chance to instantiate one yourself.

***source:*** https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674466/1672895